# Does $\frac{\cos(\ln(2n+1))}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

...if we consider the never null subsequence $\cos(\ln(2\sigma(n)+2))$...

Is the [result given by wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%28cos%28ln%282n%2B1%29%29%2Fcos%28ln%282n%2B2%29%29%2Cn%2Cinf%29) (that firstly surprised me because to me, it would converge to $1$) correct?

Been trying with $\displaystyle \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}, \ln(2n+1) = \ln(2n+2) + \ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)$ but no...

Comment: Try it with cos(ln(2)+ ln(n+1/2)) and cos(ln(2)+ ln(n+1)))

Comment: I don't think the limit exists, but if it exists it should be 1.

Comment: How to prove it converges to 1 if it is the case...? still considering it...

Comment: I used the Math Solver of Microsoft Edge for your limit, and the answer is divergent.

Comment: I believe that the sequence will diverge due to the near-miss of division-by-zero. Assuming the finiteness of the irrationality measure of $e^{\pi/2}$, I think we can turn this guess into a formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have an answer.

If for $\displaystyle n\in\mathbb{N} ~u_n = \frac{\cos(\ln(2n+1))}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}$, removing eventual null denominators, with the mean value theorem:

For all $n \in \mathbb{N},~ \exists x_n \in \,]2n+1;2n+2[~ \cos(\ln(2n+2)) = \cos(\ln(2n+1)) + f'(x_n)$

where $f(x) = \cos(\ln(x))$, for $x>0.$ So $x_n \sim 2n$.

Thus, $\displaystyle u_n= 1 + \frac{\sin(\ln(x_n))}{x_n\cos(ln(2n+2))}$.

1. If $u_n$ converges to $0$, $\sin(\ln(x_n)) \sim -2n \cos(\ln(2n+2))$, which is not possible, $\sin(\ln(x_n))$ being bounded.
2. If $u_n$ converges to $\alpha >0$, $\cos(\ln(2n+2))$ and $\cos(\ln(2n+1))$ would have the same sign from a certain rank. The thing is $v_n = \cos(\ln(n))$ is an oscillating sequence, so crosses the real axis regularly. See figure where $n =55$ .

[image: n=55]

3. If $u_n$ converges to $\alpha < 0$, $\cos(\ln(2n+1))$ and $\cos(\ln(2n+2))$ would have opposite signs from a certain rank, but $v_n$ draws larger and larger bumps when $n \rightarrow \infty$ each side of the real axis, making infinite the number of elements $(\cos(\ln(2n+1))$ and $\cos(\ln(2n+2)))$ that have the same sign. See figure where $n=101$.

[image: n=101]

So $u_n$ diverges, not converging to any real number?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is incorrect. As $\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n+1)=\ln\left(1+\frac 1{2n+1}\right)\sim\frac 1{2n+1}$, the values of cosines are asymptotically the same, so the limit should be $1$.

Note that
$$
\frac{\cos(\ln(2n+1))}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}-1
=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\ln(2n+2)+\ln(2n+1)}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{\ln(2n+2)-\ln(2n+1)}2\right)}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}
=\frac{2\sin\left(\ln(2n+2)+\frac{1+o(1)}{2(2n+1)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1+o(1)}{2n+1}\right)}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}
=\frac{1+o(1)}n\times \frac{\sin\left(\ln(2n+2)+\frac{1+o(1)}{4n)}\right)}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))}
$$
so the problem might arise only if $\cos(\ln(2n+2))$ is very close to zero, which cannot be ruled out a priori.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  It seems it does not converge.  Numerical evidence.
Consider
$$
\frac{\cos(\ln(2n+1))}{\cos(\ln(2n+2))},\qquad n \in \mathbb N .
\tag{$*$} $$

We want to get the denominator as close as possible to $0$.  The denominator would be exactly zero if
$$
\ln(2n+2) = \pi\big(k+\frac12\big),\qquad k \in \mathbb Z
\\
n = \frac{\exp\big(\pi(k+\frac12)\big)}{2}-1
$$
but that is not an integer.  So let's try
$$
n = \left\lfloor
\frac{\exp\big(\pi(k+\frac12)\big)}{2}-1
\right\rfloor,\qquad k \in \mathbb Z .
\tag1$$
Here are the values of $(*)$ where $n$ is given by $(1)$ and $k$ runs from $1$ to $100$...

[image: graph]

It looks like these values are (almost) never as small as $1$, and frequently much larger than $1$.

Comment: I agree because $\log n$ increases very slowly so the likelihood is that there will be infinitely many $n$ st $|\log n-\pi (2k+1)/2|=O(n^{-1-\epsilon})$ so the ratio is unbounded for those; not sure if one can give a formal proof with the current state of the art knowledge of $\pi$ approximations though